# If-exist-then-do condition

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and I don't get how to do this:

if exist

```
       $versions | select * | where {$_.versionid -eq "1024"}
```

then do

```
       $List.GetItemById($_.Id).file.undocheckout()
```

Comment: The 2010 (and 2007, 2013, etc) tag is for things that you think are very specific to that version of SharePoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about piping to a foreach-object:

```
 $versions | select * | where {$_.versionid -eq "1024"} | ForEach-Object { $List.GetItemById($_.Id).file.undocheckout()}
```